# How to say inversely propotional in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I simply made a div that is fixed on the right hand of the page and some contents. **What I want is** to decrease the size this div whenever my contents are bigger that the `window.innerHeight()`. And this resize must be one pixel on every one pixel increase in window's height. If someone didn't understood, can ask me in comments. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom ScrollBar</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #scrollBar{
            height: 200px;
            width: 5px;
            background: grey;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <p>is is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text.is is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text.</p>
    <div id="scrollBar"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    var scrollBar = $('#scrollBar');
    scrollBar.height($(document).height());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just forgot to remove it before copy pasting it in the question! Romoved it now!

Comment: well, you did need the window resize, if you wanted to do something when the window is resized, :p

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Something like this works for what you want, but you're going to have to build in some kind of constants. The 25000 below is just a random constant I picked to see if it would work. The constants, whatever you choose, are going to be what really dictate the change in size.

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function () {
    var changeHeight, example;
    changeHeight = function ($div) {
        var inverse, winHeight;
        winHeight = $(window).height();
        inverse = 25000 / winHeight;
        return $div.height(inverse);
    };
    example = $('.example-div');
    return changeHeight(example);
});
```

Comment: Absolutely not! This is not what I want

Comment: Well thanks for being so nice about it. Could you clarify a little more then?

Comment: Well I want to make the height of my div inversely propotional to the document height. Got it now?

Comment: Changed my answer to above. I think this is closer to what you mean.